# add "all" row to pandas group by

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

This is my code (using pandas 0.19.2)

```
import pandas as pd


data=StringIO("""category,region,sales
fruits,east,12
vegatables,east,3
fruits,west,5
vegatables,wst,7
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data)
print(df.groupby('category', as_index=False).agg({'sales': sum}))
```

This is the output:

```
     category  sales
0      fruits     17
1  vegatables     10
```

My question is: how do add an 'all' row so the output would look like this:

```
     category  sales
0      fruits     17
1  vegatables     10
          all     27
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pivot_table` and alter the new data:

```
new_df = df.pivot_table(columns='category',index='region', values='sales')

new_df['all'] = new_df.sum(1)
```

Output:

```
category  fruits  vegatables  all
region                           
east          12           3   15
west           5           7   12
```

And if you want your original data:

```
new_df.stack().to_frame(name='Sales').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  region    category  Sales
0   east      fruits     12
1   east  vegatables      3
2   east         all     15
3   west      fruits      5
4   west  vegatables      7
5   west         all     12
```

Comment: looks interesting, I should look up the pivot_table function, but I didn't want to change my solution too much, so I created somewhat hacky solution - see my own answer

Answer (score 0):

here is what i ended up doing:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

data = StringIO("""category,region,sales
fruits,east,12
vegatables,east,3
fruits,west,5
vegatables,wst,7
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data)
body=df.groupby('category', as_index=False).agg({'sales': sum})

head=df.groupby(lambda x: True, as_index=False) #advanced panda trickery
head=head.agg({'sales': sum})
head.insert(0,'category','*all*')

print(body.append(head))
```

basically, create another dataframe with the '*all*' row and concat